# haproxy : Checking for a single header

Tags: haproxy

My server is distributing websocket client connections over 4 local websocket servers.

Is it possible to instruct haProxy to accept only WebSocket version 13 (RFC 6455) ?

***i.e.*** Verify if `Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13` is set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your frontend section:

```
acl websocket13 hdr_val(Sec-WebSocket-Version) eq 13
use_backend my_backend if websocket13
```

The first line says that if the header `Sec-WebSocket-Version` equals 13, then set a flag called `websocket13`. The second line says to use the backend section `my_backend` if the `websocket13` flag is set.

Comment: and is it possible to use 'AND' operator? if websocket13 and somethingElse

Comment: Yes, it's pretty clearly explained on the manual page for use_backend. Have you looked?

Comment: Yes, I did, but found nothing except this -> eq ge gt le lt :

Comment: @Jack yes, absolutely, just put `&&`, you can check this for any other multiple conditions:
https://serverfault.com/questions/768575/haproxy-acl-multiple-or-conditions

Comment: ops, sorry, need to put this:
`if condition_1 condition2`