# HAProxy ACL multiple OR conditions

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

Using Haproxy 1.5.12 running on Ubuntu 12.04

I need to restrict access to my website to requests either coming from certain IPs or having a defined parameter in the request.

So for example the following request should work only from authorized IPs:

```
http://www-test.example.com/page.php
```

And this request should be fulfilled from any IP (including allowed ones):

```
http://www-test.example.com/page.php?devtool=1
```

My ACLs are:

```
acl is_test hdr(host) -m sub test
acl is_allowed src -f /etc/haproxy/allowed_ips
acl is_devtool urlp(devtool) 1
acl is_devtool hdr_sub(Referer) devtool=1
```

and they work fine if used exclusively:

```
http-request deny if is_test ! is_allowed
```

or

```
http-request deny if is_test ! is_devtool
```

But if I combine them with an OR I'm unable to access the URL from an allowed IP (inverting the tests doesn't help):

```
http-request deny if is_test ! is_allowed || is_test ! is_devtool
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The test you appear to be wanting to impose is this:

```
A && !(B || C)
```

...but that is not logically equivalent to what you've written, which is essentially this...

```
(A && !B) || (A && !C)
```

The logical equivalent of `A && !(B || C)` without using parentheses for precedence is actually this:

```
A && !B && !C
```

So what you're looking for should be this:

```
http-request deny if is_test !is_allowed !is_devtool
```

Or, to restate it: deny the request if --

- it matches `is_test`, **and**
- it doesn't match `is_allowed`, **and**
- it doesn't match `is_devtool`

As long as any one of these condtions is false (isn't test, is allowed, is devtool) your rule doesn't match, and doesn't deny the request.

Comment: works! thanks again @michael-sqlbot this is the second time this week, I owe you another :)

Comment: Incidentally, if you're curious, there's a name for the logical concept here -- [De Morgan's laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). *"The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.  The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations."*

Comment: error detected while parsing switching rule : no such ACL : '&&'.